# Search seperat specific wk sheet based on date in column on 1st wk sheet

Tags: vba, excel

So not sure where to start so I'll just kind of dump this out there and ask for direction.

I have a work book with no less than 40 work sheets.
In my Original (name) sheet I have 3 columns  City, date, "to be filled in"

In the next ~30 sheets I have the 2 columns city, value (Each of these sheets is named by day of the month... (1,2,3,4,etc...)

I need to put the "value" from sheets 1 - 30 into the Column "to be filled in" based on the city matching and the date column day matching the worksheet day.

So as an example:
Original sheet contains:

```
City     Date     "to be filled in"
C1      01012000        (missing)
C1      01032000        (missing)
C2      01012000        (missing)
C2      01022000        (missing)
C3      01012000        (missing)


Sheets 1-30 look like so:
Sheet 1 has:
City      Value
C1        5
C2        3
C3        1

Sheet 2 has:
City      Value
C1        3
C2        10
C3        9

Sheet 3 has:
City      Value
C1        1
C2        2
C3        2
```

So after I run the VBA code my Original work sheet should look like this:
Original sheet NOW contains:

```
City     Date     "to be filled in"
C1      01012000        5
C1      01032000        1
C2      01012000        3
C2      01022000        10
C3      01012000        1
```

So I need to search the worksheets based on the Day in the date column, looking for the city in the original sheet , once I find the city on the correct tab, I need to pull back the value in that sheet/row and populate the missing data on the original sheet.

I'd like to do it using VBA. It's kind of like a vlookup, but not, so I'm a bit stumped.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need VBA for this. Excel's magical formulas will work.
This formula will first extract the date/sheet number using the formula:

```
IF(LEFT(MID(B2,IF(LEN(B2)=8,3,2),2),1)="0",RIGHT(MID(B2,IF(LEN(B2)=8,3,2),2),1),MID(B2,IF(LEN(B2)=8,3,2),2))
```

Then concatenate it with "Sheet" to create the sheet name.

```
CONCATENATE("Sheet",IF(LEFT(MID(B2,IF(LEN(B2)=8,3,2),2),1)="0",RIGHT(MID(B2,IF(LEN(B2)=8,3,2),2),1),MID(B2,IF(LEN(B2)=8,3,2),2)), "!A:B")
```

And then use vlookup to find the value.

> =VLOOKUP(A2, INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("Sheet",IF(LEFT(MID(B2,IF(LEN(B2)=8,3,2),2),1)="0",
>   RIGHT(MID(B2,IF(LEN(B2)=8,3,2),2),1),MID(B2,IF(LEN(B2)=8,3,2),2)),
>   "!A:B"),TRUE ),2,FALSE)

If you have dates in **`1/1/2000`** format instead of **`01012000`**, than use this formula instead.

> =VLOOKUP(A2, INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("Sheet",IF(LEFT(TEXT(B2,"dd"),1)="0",
>   RIGHT(TEXT(B2,"dd"),1),TEXT(B2,"dd")), "!A:B"),TRUE ),2,FALSE)

Just place this formula in cell C2 and drag it down.

And you will get your result like this.

```
A               B             C                     D
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1   City        Date        "to be filled in"       Formula used
-----------------------------------------------------------------
2   C1          01012000       5                    =VLOOKUP(A2, INDIRECT( CONCATENATE("Sheet",IF(LEFT(MID(B2,IF(LEN(B2)=8,3,2),2),1)="0",
                                                        RIGHT(MID(B2,IF(LEN(B2)=8,3,2),2),1),MID(B2,IF(LEN(B2)=8,3,2),2)), "!A:B"),TRUE ),2,FALSE)
3   C1          01032000       1                    =VLOOKUP(A3, INDIRECT( CONCATENATE("Sheet",IF(LEFT(MID(B3,IF(LEN(B3)=8,3,2),2),1)="0",
                                                        RIGHT(MID(B3,IF(LEN(B3)=8,3,2),2),1),MID(B3,IF(LEN(B3)=8,3,2),2)), "!A:B"),TRUE ),2,FALSE)
4   C2          01012000       3                    =VLOOKUP(A4, INDIRECT( CONCATENATE("Sheet",IF(LEFT(MID(B4,IF(LEN(B4)=8,3,2),2),1)="0",
                                                        RIGHT(MID(B4,IF(LEN(B4)=8,3,2),2),1),MID(B4,IF(LEN(B4)=8,3,2),2)), "!A:B"),TRUE ),2,FALSE)
5   C2          01022000       10                   =VLOOKUP(A5, INDIRECT( CONCATENATE("Sheet",IF(LEFT(MID(B5,IF(LEN(B5)=8,3,2),2),1)="0",
                                                        RIGHT(MID(B5,IF(LEN(B5)=8,3,2),2),1),MID(B5,IF(LEN(B5)=8,3,2),2)), "!A:B"),TRUE ),2,FALSE)
6   C3          01012000       1                    =VLOOKUP(A6, INDIRECT( CONCATENATE("Sheet",IF(LEFT(MID(B6,IF(LEN(B6)=8,3,2),2),1)="0",
                                                        RIGHT(MID(B6,IF(LEN(B6)=8,3,2),2),1),MID(B6,IF(LEN(B6)=8,3,2),2)), "!A:B"),TRUE ),2,FALSE)
```

Comment: Sorry, how does it know what sheet to be looking in?

Comment: This part of the formula `INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("Sheet",IF(LEFT(MID(B2,IF(LEN(B2)=8,3,2),2),1)="0", RIGHT(MID(B2,IF(LEN(B2)=8,3,2),2),1),MID(B2,IF(LEN(B2)=8,3,2),2)), "!A:B"),TRUE )` will tell which sheet to look. Basically I have extracted the date number from column B(Date) and then concatenate to create a sheet reference. If you wil try to understand the formula by going to Formulas -> Evaluate Formulas, you'll get what I am saying.

Comment: would it be just as easy to use the day function on the date cell to get the sheet name we need t search?

Comment: Yes true, but I've used this approach as I thought you have the date in this format `01012000` in your column "Date"

Comment: See my updates, I've updated to handle correct date format.